# Call Public variable of C# in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript

**My Problem is I am try to call Public variable in Code Behind From JavaScript function
I try To Do This :**

**In Code Behind Section:**

```
  public string str ="TEST";
```

**In JavaScript Section:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function funDoSomething()
    {
        var strMessage = '<%= str%>';
        alert( strMessage );
    }
 </script>
```

**Any Suggestion?**

Comment: you didn't ask a question actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the answer and it is Like this
In JavaScript Section:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

   function funDoSomething()
   {
       var strMessage = "<%=str%>";
       alert( strMessage );
   }
</script>
```

**This Work With Me** :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">    
    function funDoSomething()
    {
        var strMessage = <%= "'" + str + "'"%>;
        alert( strMessage );
    }
 </script>
```

Ugly but should work.